# Python - Return integer value for list enumeration

Tags: python, enumerate

Is there a cleaner way to get an integer value of the position of a list item in this code:

```
a = ['m', 'rt', 'paaq', 'panc']
loc = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == 'rt']
loc_str = str(loc).strip('[]')
loc_int = int(loc_str)
id_list = a[loc_int + 1:]
print id_list
```

Returns all items after 'rt' as a list ['paaq', 'panc']

Comment: I think it's important that you realize that you don't need to convert your list `loc` to `str` just to get the first element. Just use `a[loc[0]+1:]`.

Comment: You know `enumerate`, you work with list comprehensions and you don't know about slicing which is covered in the first parts of the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)? That's truly wondrous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use `list.index()`.

```
a = ['m', 'rt', 'paaq', 'panc']
id_list = a[a.index('rt')+1:]
assert id_list == ['paaq', 'panc']
```

Or, to minimally change your program:

```
a = ['m', 'rt', 'paaq', 'panc']
loc_int = a.index('rt')
id_list = a[loc_int + 1:]
print id_list
```

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange
- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Answer (score 0):

```
a[a.index('rt') + 1:]
```

What this is doing is [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) the array, starting at where `a.index('rt')`. not specifying an end `:]` means we want until the end of the list.